# Extrinsic Size Determination (CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3)

Tags: html, css

In the [Extrinsic Size Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#extrinsic) chapter of the [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3), we can read:

> Sometimes the size of a percentage-sized box’s containing block
>   depends on the intrinsic size contribution of the box itself, creating
>   a cyclic dependency. When calculating the containing block’s size, the
>   percentage behaves as auto. Then, unless otherwise specified, when
>   calculating the used sizes and positions of the containing block’s
>   contents:
>
> - If the cyclic dependency was introduced due to a **block-size** or **max-block-size** on the containing block that causes it to depend on the
>     size of its contents, the box’s percentage is not resolved and instead
>     behaves as auto.
> - Otherwise, the percentage is resolved against the containing block’s size. (The containing block’s size is not re-resolved based on the
>     resulting size of the box; the contents might thus overflow or
>     underflow the containing block).

And:

> Note: These rules specify the previously-undefined behavior of this
>   cyclic case in [CSS2§10.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property). Note also, the behavior in
>   [CSS2§10.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) is superseded in their respective specifications for
>   layout modes (such as flex layout) not described in CSS2.

So, assuming `horizontal-tb` `writing-mode`, we know from the **first bullet** that percentage **height** (aka. block-size) of child is set to `auto`, if parent size is based on child (i.e. they form a cyclical definition).

Then, the second bullet says that percentage is actually resolved for cyclical **widths**. So, in the case of width (which unlike height, was undefined in CSS2 in cyclical cases), it should be resolved as a percentage.

**My Question**
For the second bullet, how is it possible to resolve width as a percentage, when it is cyclical? Percentage of what containing block size?

---

**EDIT**

In the examples it shows that width also becomes `auto`, which makes me wonder if it was a typo that the auto transformation rule should only apply to `block size` (aka. height in `horizontal-tb` `writing-mode`)

Comment: because width doesn't depend on the content so we can resolve the percentage. A block element will always be as wide as its parent and the same for his parent and so on .. that's we can also have overflow if we use more than 100% (no? )

Comment: Hi @temaniafif . No, you could actually easily specify an inline-size (aka. width in horizontal writing-mode), and create a cyclical dependency. For instance, containing block's `width` is set to `min-content` while content's width is set to a percentage. I actually figured it out though. The algorithm runs in two steps. 1) First containing block's size is calculated as if percentage content is has auto size. This goes for both dimensions. 2) Then, content size is calculated, using those two bullets above. It is actually quite well explained in the examples.

Comment: ah yes in this case percentage won't work if you said to the width to be the size of the content and then the content to be based on the size of the container. It will fall to auto

Comment: @temaniafif Yep, for inline-size (width in my writing-mode) it will fall to auto in order to calculate containing block's width, but then it will resolve as a percentage when calculating content width. This is only the case for width, because width was undefined in cyclical cases in CSS2. Height, was defined to be auto in CSS2, so CSS3 remains compliant with that (as seen in bullet one).

Comment: hmm true https://jsfiddle.net/0pmwc7u5/ .. I never thought it will happen like this

Comment: Yes. I am loving the Level 3 specs :). Now gone through a lot of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the second bullet, how is it possible to resolve width as a percentage, when it is cyclical? Percentage of what containing block size?

Refer back to the first paragraph of the first quote, which contains this sentence:

> When calculating the containing block’s size, the percentage behaves as auto.

This first step is crucial. There's no way to determine the size of the containing block except by giving the content an arbitrary size. That size is auto. However for the sake of consistency the width of the content is then calculated as the specified percentage, the percentage itself based off of this freshly calculated containing block size.

This has been the interoperable behavior of browsers for years and years now, so nothing really has changed except that the behavior is now specified.